# Comic-book: Kids find a dead female superhero in the woods

Tags: story-identification, comics, super-hero

It was an early 2000s comic book, most surely from the USA. I think it was the first number in a series. Four high school boys and girls find the body of a female superhero in the woods.

Most of the story was about the lives of teenagers. One boy was a conflictive student with a dysfunctional family, one of the girls was obese.

I've been searching the internet for "kids find dead superhero woman in the woods" without finding anything relevant and I don't recommend you to do the same. Bing gives many results with pictures of "dead women" and "dead kids". I'm afraid it's an usual search.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is likely *[Plutona](https://imagecomics.com/comics/releases/plutona-1)*, a 5 issue miniseries by Image.

[image: Trade paperback of *Plutona*]

> A brand new heartfelt super-hero series by JEFF LEMIRE (DESCENDER, Hawkeye) and amazing newcomer EMI LENOX! PLUTONA follows the story of five suburban kids who make a shocking discovery while exploring the woods one day after school...the body of Plutona, the world's greatest superhero. A dark and heartbreaking journey about friendship and coming of age all through the lens of the superhero genre.

Found via *"comic book" "dead superheroine" woods* on Google.

[The TVTropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/ComicBook/Plutona) has further notes of dysfunctionality in the families, although there are also some big spoilers.

> **Abusive Parents**: Ray's dad is a neglectful alcoholic who can't hold down a job.
>   .....
>   **Sour Outside, Sad Inside**: Ray acts like a jerk because he's insecure about his home situation. Given the opportunity to hang out with people he trusts, he's ok.

Comment: The OP remembers four kids, but there are five on the cover, so that is a discrepancy. However, they do remember an obese girl, which matches the girl in the green hoodie (relative to the other kids).

Comment: Side note: Several pages that came up for me with that search didn't load, but I was able to use the cached page. Some other ones were referring to the death of "Retro-Girl" in *Powers*. Potential confounders and all that.

Comment: @Thunderforge Hardly a discrepancy worth mentioning. How could OP possibly accurately remember whether it was 4 or 5 kids?

Comment: @only_pro I'm the OP and I can confirm that you're right. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots This is the right answer. By the way, I never use Google because of principles, but this answer is a new proof that Bing sucks.

Comment: Ah, well, I'm biased because I work for Google, but their search does tend to be pretty good. :) To the point where there are search engines which start by just repeating Google results.

Comment: @Ginasius: And no hurries, of course, but don't forget to accept the answer. :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Will not forget, don't worry. I use to take a couple of days to accept because IMHO too early accepted answers use to be less noticed. ;)